# Angular Mat Select Multiple selectionchange finding which option was changed

Tags: angular, angular-material, multi-select

I have a `<mat select>` with the `multiple` option set (a multi-select). When the `selectionChange` event fires I need to know which option has been checked or unchecked, however, it only returns the new current list of selected options.

For instance I have a list:

```
<mat-select (selectionChange)="change($event)" multiple placeholder="Select">
  <mat-option value="1">one</mat-option>
  <mat-option value="2">two</mat-option>
  <mat-option value="3">three</mat-option>
  <mat-option value="4">four</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

If options `one`, `three` and `four` are checked and then the user unchecked option `four`, in the event handler I need to know which option triggered the event (i.e. option `four`) and its new state. I currently don't see a way of accessing that information in the `selectionChange` event.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1e9gsd?file=app/select-overview-example.ts

I tried putting the event handler `(selectionChange)="change($event)"` on the `<mat-option>` but it doesn't seem to be supported.

Comment: Do you have in the event, console.log(event.value);

Comment: ``new selection`` is not the ``new value`` ? can you explain ? ``console.log(event.value);`` looks good to me. it looks like you have to clarify your question.

Comment: sorry. I messed up the example... it was suppose to be a multi select, like the title says... fixed the example now. Event.value gives back an array of everything selected. I just want the new thing that was selected, preferably without caching the old selected value and doing a compare to find whats changed.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

I needed to use `onSelectionChange` on the `<mat-option>`, which is different than the `selectionChange` that you can use on the `<mat-select>`

It would be nice if that was in the documentation for `mat-select`.

Here it is working https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1e9gsd-34hrwg?file=app/select-overview-example.html

Comment: Do you know where any documentation is for the mat-option? I could only find the API for the mat-select

Comment: @NickGallimore I also couldnt find any documentation for `<mat-option>`

Comment: @Curtis Upvote this issue https://github.com/angular/components/issues/8790 For the meantime you can use this to see which Output and Input the component has https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/core/option/option.ts

Comment: This approach works but fires so many events unnecessarily so it is not an excellent approach to go with

Answer (score 10):

Here is alternative solution. `onSelectionChange` event is fired before `[(ngModel)]` is bound. In my case, I needed both bound data and last selected value.

```html
<mat-select
  multiple
  [(ngModel)]="selectedValues"
  name="hebele"
  #select
>
  <mat-option
    *ngFor="let value of data.Values"
    (click)="yourMethod(matOption)"
    [value]="value"
    #matOption
  >
    {{value.Text}}
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

```js
yourMethod(data: any) {
  let lastSelectedValue = data.value;
  const isChecked = data.selected;
}
```

Comment: Works brilliant! Thx

Answer (score -2):

This worked for me. `blahs` is an array of strings in this case. Use [2-way binding](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview#getting-and-setting-the-select-value):

```
<mat-select placeholder="choose..." [(value)]="selected" 
      (selectionChange)="somethingChanged(selected)">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let b of blahs; index as i;" value={{b[i]}}">{{b[i]}}
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Comment: This is a standard select. The question is referring to a multi select. This proposed solution would output only the current value of the multi select. Not which option was checked or unchecked during a change selection change event.