# Angular 5 : Event handling for material dropdown

Tags: angular, angular-material

I need to call a function in case there is a change in the value of `mat-select`.
I have been calling that function on `(click)` added to `mat-option.`

But if we just use the keyboard to fill up the form, the function is never called(Understandably).
Is there any way I can call the function on any change? onChange, change events don't appear to work.
I don't have `ngModel` on this form-field

Update:
`selectionChange` works for single select drop-downs but not for `multi-select` drop-downs and `mat-autocomplete`.Is there a way this can be achieved?
Multi Select Example: [multi-select-stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-with-angular-v5-jsgvx6?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Update 2:
onSelectionChange for multiple and autocomplete works.[multi-autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50617063/9491345)

Comment: use selectionChange to get selected value from the mat-select. please check answer for detail

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you can use the `(selectionChange)` event on mat-select.

**Example :**

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder="State" (selectionChange)="someMethod($event.value)">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let state of states" [value]="state.value">
            {{ state.viewValue }}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

**[Here is Demo on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-stackoverflow-9wpyd8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Fstackoverflow-solution%2Fstackoverflow-solution.component.html)**

Comment: This works for single select dropdown!But for multiple select drop-down in which I have a select all functionality it does not work.
Please see https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-with-angular-v5-jsgvx6?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 2):

There's a **`selectionChange`** Event Emitter in material select which emits the value whenever the user changes the option inside the `mat-select`, please refer the [docs here](https://material.angular.io/components/select/api)

```
<mat-select placeholder="State" (selectionChange)="someMethod($event.value)">

</mat-select>
```