# how to get the selected value <mat-select> from HTML into ts file?

Tags: angular

I am trying to get the selected value from  HTML into ts file . Below is the HTML code which uses Angular material tags

```
      <mat-form-field [style.visibility]="visibility" >
              <mat-label>Apps</mat-label>
              <mat-select #selectedApp (change)='fetchTableData($event)'>
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let apps of appsList$" [value]="apps.appName">{{apps.appName}}</mat-option>
                    <mat-option [value]="all">All</mat-option>
              </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
```

.ts code

```
     @ViewChild('selectedApp') selectedApp;

     ngOnInit() {             
             return this.testcaseService.getAll()
         .subscribe(apps => this.appsList$ = apps);

      }

     fetchTableData(event: any){                  

        console.log("Selected App: "+this.selectedApp.Selected);
      }
```

I am not sure what am i doing wrong here . Can anyone help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use selectionChange event binding from mat-select.

https://material.angular.io/components/select/api

Comment: thanks . I have followed your suggestion and this solution - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50614991/angular-mat-select-multiple-selectionchange-finding-which-option-was-changed , but this is also not working for me . I am wondering what i have done wrong here ?

Comment: what version of angular material are you using ?

Comment: "@angular/cli": "~7.3.8"

Comment: Thanks Prasanth  , i have modified (change) to (selectionChange) , it worked perfectly fine now . Google changed the syntax from angular 6 , it seems .

Answer (score 0):

Change your `(change)` event to `fetchTableData($event.value)`

```
 <mat-form-field [style.visibility]="visibility" >
              <mat-label>Apps</mat-label>
              <mat-select #selectedApp (change)='fetchTableData($event.value)'>
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let apps of appsList$" [value]="apps.appName">{{apps.appName}}</mat-option>
                    <mat-option [value]="all">All</mat-option>
              </mat-select>
 </mat-form-field>
```

and use event as selected value

```
fetchTableData(event: any) {

    console.log("Selected App: " + event);
  }
```

Demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-data-2

You should not use `this.selectedApp.Selected`

Comment: I have tried the above solution . its not working ,  Could there be any other issue ?

Comment: thanks . i checked your code and it looks perfectly fine . but somehow its not working in my local . when i change the option from dropdown , the control does not go into fetchTableData(event) in ts .  I don't get any errors in console or anything that i can debug . weird .