# how to dynamically change background color of a button in angular material without the need to click on it

Tags: angular, typescript, button, dynamic, background

I'm trying to construct a web page using angular material
where I have a drop-down select element and a bunch of FAB buttons to show status.
What I would like to do is that if a click on the dropdown list and select an item.
The background color of the button is changed based on the item I select.

I've found a few solutions to change color(scheme) based on button click event.
Is there a way to trigger the background color change based on the drop-down list selection?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger the function that changes the button color each time the item selected has been changed using this code :

```
  <mat-select (selectionChange)="setButtonColor($event.value)"
              name="color" formControlName="type" >
       <mat-option *ngFor="let color of colors" 
                   [value]="color">{{type}}
        </mat-option>
   </mat-select>

   <button mat-button [ngStyle]="{'background-color':bgColor}">
      Button
   </button>
```

your Typescript file should contain a variable bgColor to hold the selected value string and the setButtonColor function that change the value of this variable

```
bgColor = 'blue'; // blue is the default color in this case

setButtonColor(color){
    bgColor = color;
}
```

Comment: I've got an error in html file on the line of <mat-select (selectionChange)="setButtonColor($event.value)": Property 'setButtonColor' does not exist on type ...  I do have the setbuttonColor declared as you suggested.

Comment: let colors: string[] = ['green', 'red', 'orange'];   
bgColor = 'green';
setButtonColor(color) {
  bgcolor = color;
}

Comment: @JinMa make sure `setButtonColor` is public: `public setButtonColor(color) { bgcolor = color; }`

Answer (score 0):

[Angular Mat Select Multiple selectionchange finding which option was changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50614991/angular-mat-select-multiple-selectionchange-finding-which-option-was-changed)

The answer to the above question helped me.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1e9gsd-34hrwg?file=app/select-overview-example.html
I tweaked my code based on the code shown above and it all worked.