# How to get selected index of selected value in Mat-Select Option in Angular 7+

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have code like this

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select  id="selectNow" placeholder="{{data?.chatMessage?.labelText}}" (selectionChange)="dropDownActionEvent($event,selected,'selection_change'); display($event)" [(value)]="selected">
    <mat-option>None</mat-option>
    <mat-option (click)="onSelect(i)" *ngFor="let x of merged;" [value]="x.data">
      {{x.labels}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

I want selected index of selected value
i am doing like below but not able to get selected index

```js
var index = document.getElementById("selectNow").selectedIndex;
document.write(index);
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using `document` methods in Angular. You can use template-driven or reactive forms to always have access to the currently selected element. I suggest you look at the Forms section of Angular's documentation.

Comment: not able to get selected index

Comment: You absolutely can. Angular offers many many approaches, including that suggested by @MuhammadUmar below. We're not going to code it for you, you need to put in the work yourself here.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use **vanillaJS** ways to manipulate/get dom. Angular offers some handy ways to access/manipulate dom.
you are using the right attriube to get the event, but you are placing it in the wrong tag. Place **(selectionChange)** inside **mat-option** tag. For a working example refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50617063/15282385) answer's [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1e9gsd-92w5f4?file=app/select-overview-example.html). This example showcases **onSelectionChange** which also fulfills the result you are looking for

Comment: not able to get selected index

Comment: can you make a stackblitz of your code